# Can I get AssignedToId using rest api

Tags: javascript, tasks, sharepoint-rest-api

I need to get AssignedToId, I have threshold 5000 items so i can't using filter.
This code throws error at : AssignedTo.Id. Help me fix this?

```
$.ajax({
   url: "<domain>/_api/lists(guid'285E8476-12D6-44BE-BFB2-C8810B96165C')/items",
   type: "GET",
   headers: {"Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"},
   success: function (data){
     var dataArray = data.d.results;
         for (var i in dataArray) {
            if(dataArray[i].Status!='Chua Ba´t dâ`u'&&dataArray[i].AssignedTo.Id==_spPageContextInfo.userId){ 
                $("#container-tqv").append("<div>"+  data.d.results[i].Title+ " </div>"); 
            }
         }
        dfd.resolve();
    },
   error: function(response){ 
        console.log('khong the load duoc do: '+ response.statusText); 
        dfd.reject();
   }
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Please check your URL. "Web" seems to be missing in your URL :

Please try to Use below URL :

```
url : "<domain>/_api/web/lists(guid'285E8476-12D6-44BE-BFB2-C8810B96165C')/items"
```

Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx